# 400 if Pageable cannot be parsed

Tags: spring-boot, rest, parsing, pageable

Recently I was informed about a bug.
The tester executed the following request:

```
curl -X 'GET' 'http://zones:26081/zones/vehicles-by-day?date=2023-05-20&page=0&size=10&sort=string'
```

And got 500 error in response:

```
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"detail":"No property 'string' found for type 'VehiclesByDayEntity'","instance":"/zones/vehicles-by-day"}
```

However she expected a 400 status which is reasonable. If `org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable` cannot be parsed it should be considered as a bad request.

Below is the excerpt from the `@RestController` code:

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
...
@GetMapping(value = "/vehicles-by-day", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity<VehiclesByDay200Response> getVehiclesByDay(
        @Parameter(name = "date", description = "The date vehicles by day which for")
        @RequestParam(value = "date", required = false) LocalDate date,
        @Parameter(name = "pageable", in = ParameterIn.QUERY)
        @PageableDefault Pageable pageable
);
```

Is there a way to detect (intercept) the parsing error and return the 400 status instead of 500 ?

For example if I use a wrong date value in the request I'll get 400.

```
curl -X 'GET' 'http://zones:26081/zones/vehicles-by-day?date=2023-05-aa&page=0&size=10'
{"type":"about:blank","title":"Bad Request","status":400,"detail":"Failed to convert 'null' with value: '2023-05-aa'","instance":"/zones/vehicles-by-day"}
```

Why is it different with `Pageable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own exception handler to do this. The exception that's being thrown is `PropertyReferenceException`. For example, you could write something like this:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(PropertyReferenceException.class)
public ErrorResponse propertyReferenceExceptionHandler(PropertyReferenceException ex) {
    return ErrorResponse.create(ex, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Either add this to your controller, or to a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`.